wildcard in powershell script command for file paths, How to apply that to like 100 profiles in a group policy
So if i use this powershell script to delete files every 15 days it works great
$CutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\Programs" | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $CutOffDate } | Remove-Item

for one folder but what if I wanted a script where the url stays the same they only thing that changes is the username Z:Profiles\Users\only this changes\AppData\Local\Temp
is there a command or shortcut to ignore that part and search for the next link in the chain the AppData folder like a wild card command where the script will just go down the line in the files no matter what the username is?
basically I want to delete the contents of each users temp folder every 15 days and im not sure how to do it

* e.g., Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:Profiles\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp"

Z:\Profiles\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp

Delete $Env:Temp\ files for All Users based CreationTime max 15 days.
Edited needed according the object.
$CutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$AllTemp    = "$($Env:Temp.Replace("$Env:Username",'*'))"
Get-ChildItem -path $AllTemp -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $CutOffDate} | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Another short format:
gci "$($Env:Temp.Replace(`"$Env:UserName`",'*'))" -r | ? CreationTime -lt (Date).AddDays(-14) | ri -r -fo 2>$Nul


even in longer form there is no need to waste a scriptblock for Where-Object

This is a bit dangerous - you don't know the username convention used is, there might be a Thomas Emp with username temp, now you've accidentally deleted everything under the local appdata folder for that user :)
